# Chart.js how to show cursor pointer for labels & legends in line chart

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have the following example of line chart using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org). I want to show:

1. Pointer cursor for legend & labels on hover
2. Show all the label data on line hover

```js
 var line_chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                    data: [15, 25, 15],
                    label: "My Dataset1",
                    borderColor: "#00F",
                    fill: false
                }, {
                    data: [35, 15, 25],
                    label: "My Dataset2",
                    borderColor: "#F00",
                    fill: false
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {

            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'label'
            },
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:80%'>
<canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### Better Approach

no need of jQuery to select canvas element (`line-chart`).

**1 ▸ Solution :**

add the following in your chart options :

```
   legend: {
      onHover: function(e) {
         e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      }
   },
   hover: {
      onHover: function(e) {
         var point = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
         if (point.length) e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
         else e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
      }
   }
```

**2 ▸ Solution :**

set tooltip­*'s* **`mode`** to **`dataset`** :

```
tooltips: {
   mode: 'dataset'
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var line_chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [{
         data: [15, 25, 15],
         label: "My Dataset1",
         borderColor: "#00F",
         fill: false
      }, {
         data: [35, 15, 25],
         label: "My Dataset2",
         borderColor: "#F00",
         fill: false
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'dataset',
      },
      legend: {
         onHover: function(e) {
            e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
         }
      },
      hover: {
         onHover: function(e) {
            var point = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
            if (point.length) e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            else e.target.style.cursor = 'default';
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:80%'>
   <canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution it works like a charm but for 2nd my requirement is different i want to show value above the circle when hover on line anywhere

Comment: uhm.. I am afraid, that's not possible :/ you must hover over the points to show tooltips. also in dataset mode tooltip will always show at center. (that's a bug with chartjs I guess) and there is no other methods to achieve that.

Comment: then it is possible to highlight legend on hover?

Comment: on point hover? yes, possible. but there's no straight forward way. you might need to create a chart plugin.

Comment: ha ha ha :) dont have that much time. just one little help now i have hollow legends but i want solid.

Comment: set `backgroundColor` for your datasets.

Comment: Superb! Works like a charm!

Comment: As of Chart.js v3  `e.native.target` is needed instead of `e.target`. See migrating guide `options.onHover now receives a wrapped event as the first parameter. The previous first parameter value is accessible via event.native.`

Answer (score 30):

With Chart.js **3.x** and **4.x**:

```js
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.native.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

With Chart.js **2.x**:

```js
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

Comment: 3.x version still works in 4.4 Sep 2023

Answer (score 11):

- As of Chart js version 3.5.1 the onHover() option looks slightly different and the [method](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#removal-of-public-apis) to find the points has changed as well.
- 'target' is nested one more level under 'e.native'
- By setting interaction mode to 'index' I'm able to see my combined chart values in the one tooltip on hover.

  ```
  options: {
     interaction: { mode: 'index' },
     onHover: function (e) {
       const points = this.getElementsAtEventForMode(
         e,
         'index', { axis: 'x', intersect: true },
         false
       );

       if (points.length) e.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
       else e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
     }
  }
  ```

[image: Cursor Pointer & Combined Tooltip]

Comment: You saved me from hours of surfing the web.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on @joshfindit's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70191235/807838), for anyone that's looking for a Typescript solution for chart.js v3.5.1:

```js
onHover: (event, activeElements) => {
   (event?.native?.target as HTMLElement).style.cursor =
        activeElements?.length > 0 ? 'pointer' : 'auto';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ChartJs 2 provides `onHover` and `onLeave` [handlers](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html). We can use them to change the cursor:

```
  legend: {
    display: true,
    onHover: function (e) {
      e.target.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    },
    onLeave: function (e) {
      e.target.style.cursor = 'default'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [@ɢʀᴜɴᴛ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150374/2328064) and [@Fred Lintz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278461/2328064), I finally arrived at this on Chart js version 3.5.1:

```js
  onHover: (event, activeElements) => {
    if (activeElements?.length > 0) {
      event.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
      event.native.target.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
  },
```

Note: There is another option of using `document.getElementById('myChart').style.cursor = 'pointer';` which works well, it's just not as clean as I would like it since it sets the cursor for the whole chart, but it will survive if Chart.js changes the API again.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using react-chartjs-2 wrapper for chartjs. This might help you.

In react-chartjs-2 we can make the legends have cursor as pointer using the following configuration for the options prop.

```
const options = {
    plugins: {
        legends: {
            onHover: (event) => {
                event.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me quite some time, but almost none of the other answers work with the latest version of ChartJS (3.7.0 as of now). In the current version, there is a simple way to configure this behavior for all charts:

```js
Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onHover = function() { 
   document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer'; 
};

Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onLeave = function() { 
   document.body.style.cursor = 'unset'; 
};
```

More details can be found in the official documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

Comment: This works for me on version 3.5.1, contrary to all other "solutions" found on StackOverflow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery grabbing chart selector which is `line-chart`.

```
hover: {
  onHover: function(e, el) {
      $("#line-chart").css("cursor", el[0] ? "pointer" : "default");
    }
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snxzLvpf/1/)

Comment: Great work!! Thank you so much. But how can i show all the labels data on hover of line

Answer (score 0):

As other folks pointed out for others frameworks, in Vue is needed to aim `native` property. In addition, the `target` would be the `canvas` so you need to:

```
onHover: function (e) {
  e.native.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
},
onLeave: function (e) {
  e.native.target.style.cursor = "default";
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is 5 years old and in 2022 using the version 3.x.x of [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/) this snippet can be a good alternative.

```js
const isArray = a => a instanceof Array
const isNull = a => a == null
const cursor = a => {
  if (isNull(a)) return 'default'
  if (!isArray(a)) return 'pointer'
  if (isArray(a) && a.length > 0) return 'pointer'

  return 'default'
}

const $canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const onHover = (e, item) => {
  $canvas.style.cursor = cursor(item)
}
const onLeave = () => {
  $canvas.style.cursor = 'default'
}

const lineChart = new Chart($canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [15, 25, 15],
      label: "My Dataset1",
      borderColor: "#00F",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [35, 15, 25],
      label: "My Dataset2",
      borderColor: "#F00",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    onHover,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        onHover,
        onLeave,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="180"></canvas>
```