# How to change cursor on chartjs doughnut chart hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, charts, chart.js

I have a doughnut chart created with chartjs. I want to chart the mouse cursor to "pointer" when I hover any of the doughnut sections. How do I do that? Here is my code

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="50" height="40"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const data2 = {
    labels: {{chart_labels|safe}},
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: {{chart_data|safe}},
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      ],
      hoverOffset: 4
    }]
  };
  var ctx = $('#myChart')
    .get(0)
    .getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data2
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/su5fgb5h/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give cursor:"pointer" to the canvas element. `<canvas id="myChart" width="50" height="40" style="cursor: pointer;"></canvas>`

Comment: This change the pointer to the entire chart. I wanted to change the cursor only when hover the doughnut sections and the legend.

Comment: Can you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149062/chart-js-how-to-show-cursor-pointer-for-labels-legends-in-line-chart