# How to change cursor on hover of data labels in chart.js version 3?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I've been trying to change the mouse cursor to 'pointer' as soon as it is hovered on the data label.

I'm effectively able to achive this effect while hovering over data-points, so that is fine.

```
options: {
onHover: (eve, legendItems, chartElement) => {
      if (_.get(eve, 'native.target.style')) {
        eve.native.target.style.cursor = legendItems[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
      }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow this current documentation for the ChartDataLabels Plugin : https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/events.html#example

```
listeners: {
          click: ({ datasetIndex, dataIndex }) => {
            setTileActive(report.id);
            populateDrills(report.id, reportGroup, report.data.dataset[datasetIndex].values[dataIndex]);
            executeScroll();
            return;
          },
          enter: async (context) => {
            context.hovered = true;
            const chartTileElem = document.getElementById(`${report.id}-chart`);
            console.log('<><><><', chartTileElem.style.cursor, context);

            // _.set(context, 'chart.canvas.style.cursor', 'pointer');

            _.set(chartTileElem, 'style.cursor', 'pointer');

            // context.chart.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            return;
          },
          leave: (context) => {
            context.hovered = false;

            // const chartTileElem = document.getElementById(`${report.id}-chart`);
            // chartTileElem.style.cursor = 'default';

            // context.chart.canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
            return;
          },
          color: (context) => {
            return context.hovered ? 'green' : null;
          }
        }
```

This does re-render the chart but doesn't change the cursor to pointer when needed. One weird behaviour I've found out is that it does change cursor to pointer in some of the bar-charts when the hovered item is of the highest value in that chart. Again, that happens rarely.

So please do suggest any solid solution that would change the cursor on hover of the data label.

EDIT-1: the suggested similar question: [Chart.js how to show cursor pointer for labels & legends in line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149062/chart-js-how-to-show-cursor-pointer-for-labels-legends-in-line-chart)

differs a lot from this one. As it talks about the onHover behaviour on labels and legends, where as, in this thread I'm trying to find a solution for the data labels that gets rendered on top of the chart's data points.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js how to show cursor pointer for labels & legends in line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149062/chart-js-how-to-show-cursor-pointer-for-labels-legends-in-line-chart)

Comment: @Olian04 No. I already have the the general onHover function too, which works on the data points. The specific answer, doesn't seem to target the data labels. Should I raise this question in chartjs-datalabel-plugin's github?

Comment: I don't know enough about chart.js to determine if this is an intended behavior or not. I'd say, give it a day or two here on SO. Hopefully someone else comes along that can help you.

Comment: @Olian04 oaky sure, I'd be waiting. Thanks for helping words :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the canvas element from the context and set the cursor to pointer on that like so:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)

const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        listeners: {
          enter: (ctx) => {
            ctx.chart.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer'
          },
          leave: (ctx) => {
            ctx.chart.canvas.style.cursor = 'default'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I've put console.logs in those function. They do run pretty well, but they are showing me stale values. Like previos state available values. In most of the data points they just stick to cursor "default". So the lines `context.chart.style.cursor = 'pointer'` never gets executed for some reason.

Comment: Idk what your code looks like in the function you call to change your pointer but as you can see in my example the hover works just fine and changes the pointer

Comment: I wonder what I'm doing wrong here. I'm doing almost/exact same thing. :(